# Authorize SSL connection via proxy on Python 2.6.6

Tags: sockets, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, python-2.6

I am using fiddler as a proxy and trying to open a connection to an application.
Here are the steps:

`Proxy Code:`

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

timeval = struct.pack('ll', 3, 0)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, timeval)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
s.connect((ip_addr, port)) #Proxy connection

request_header = "CONNECT {0}:{1} HTTP/1.1\r\n".format(HOST, 443)
s.send(request_header)

request_header = "Host: {0}:{1}\r\n".format(HOST, 443)
s.send(request_header)

request_header = "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
s.send(request_header)

request_header = "\r\n"
s.send(request_header)

recvd = s.recv(1024)
```

*HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established*

Now I am using this socket to connect to the application:

`Code:`

```
header_format ='''GET /db/cert/im/d HTTP/1.1\r
Host: {0}\r
Content-Type: text/html\r
Accept: <relevant details>\r
\r

'''
s_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, keyfile="test_cert.key", \
    certfile="test_cert.pem", server_side=False, do_handshake_on_connect=True)
request_header = header_format.format(HOST)
s_sock.write(request_header)
data = s_sock.read()
print data
```

`DATA:`

**HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized

WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=""

Server: SomeServer

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Length: 35**

> I want to know how to access the site with PKI security using proxy?

**UPDATED**
*The progress I made so far, I am trying to use httplib and urllib2*

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
    'http': ip_port,
    'https': ip_port
})
```

Below implementation copied from here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30937625/4268132)

```
class HTTPSClientAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    def __init__(self, key, cert):
        urllib2.HTTPSHandler.__init__(self)
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert
    def https_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(self.getConnection, req)
    def getConnection(self, host, timeout=300):
        return  httplib.HTTPSConnection(host,
                                             key_file=self.key,
                                             cert_file=self.cert,
                                             timeout=timeout)



def open_url(url, key, cert):

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(HTTPSClientAuthHandler(key, cert))
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    opener.addheaders = [
        ("User-Agent", "<custom>"),
        ("Accept", "<custom>"),
    ]
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print response.read()
```

`The above implementation works properly, as soon as I add proxy handler I get 401 error.`
`opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy,HTTPSClientAuthHandler(key, cert))`

```
File "test_proxy.py", line 54, in open_url
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Comment: *"I want to know how to do cert, key authentication here?"*  - you are already doing this correctly. But it looks like the server is (additionally?) expecting basic authentication which you can see in the `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=""`. Basic authentication has nothing to do with certificate based authentication but is based on username and password.

Comment: What I want is to avoid username and password based authentication and force it to do cert/key based one.

Comment: A client cannot force the server to accept certificate based authentication. It is fully up to the server what methods of authentication gets accepted.

Comment: I am able to access that site following the example given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30937625/4268132, but I need to do that using a proxy.

Comment: It might be then that the specific server does not like your specific HTTP request which is likely different from the one send with httplib (for example I'm pretty sure that httplib will not send the `Content-type` header you use and which does not make any sense for  a GET request) and that's why ask for additional authentication. I suggest that you use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) which can do both deal with client certificates and also deal properly with proxies by its own (which httplib does not seem to do).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Tried with requests. `response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, cert=(cert,key))`, still getting _<Response [401]>_. asa i remove the proxy option, it works well

Comment: That's pretty strange. Could it be that there is some additional  authentication by IP address and that the server is only accepting requests from a specific IP address and not from the proxies IP address?